# Php результат в js

Tags: javascript, php, json

Есть php код который вернёт true или false  можно ли через json encode получить это значение? Конвертировать для js

Comment: `var a = <?php echo json_encode(true); ?>;`

Comment: А можно вместо true написать имя переменной да?

Comment: Да, но если эта переменная не булевая, то нужно ее преобразовать

Comment: Все спасибо большое

Comment: а просто `<?= $x ? 'true' : 'false' ?>` вас чем не устраивает?

Comment: Так не могу использовать. Функция даёт значение true false в php а мне нужно их обрабатывать в js